# Получение HTML страницы из Flask

Tags: python, flask

Могу ли я с помощью Flask запросить весь код HTML страницы?
К примеру мне нужно пропарсить код со страницы своего же сайта (парсить удобнее чем другие возможные варианты). Есть две страницы, с помощью action происходит переход с первой страницы на вторую. И мне нужно получить HTML код первой страницы чтобы пропарсить во второй, как это можно сделать? Гугл мне не помог к сожалению.

```
@application.route('/results', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results():
    return render_template('results.html')

@application.route('/results_table', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results_table():
    ТУТ К ПРИМЕРУ НУЖНО ПОПАРСИТЬ СТРАНИЦУ RESULTS ПРЕДВАРИТЕЛЬНО ЕЕ ЗАПРОСИВ И ПОЛУЧИТЬ В ВИДЕ HTML
    return render_template('results_table.html')
```

Comment: Вызов `results()` вернет вам `html` страницы.

Comment: @Roman Konoval
Но на сколько я понимаю, вызов results() запускает эту функцию повторно, я не прав? Хотелось бы этого избежать
Нет ли такого метода как на подобии: transcript = request.form['transcript'];
Только для получения всего HTML, а не отдельного элемента?

Comment: Не понятно что вы хотите и чем не устраивает вызов функции. Вам нужен весь текст html, так? Его генерирует функция `results`. Другого способа получить html кроме как вызвать эту функцию - нет (разве что сделать дубликат, который будет делать то же что и функция). И что значит `повторно`? Она будет вызвана один раз при вызове `/results_table`. Если речь о том, что перед этим вызывался `/results`, то можно во время этого вызова сохранить результат временно (только тут возникают новые проблемы: наверно ж это нужно делать не всегда? потом результат нужно чистить. как долго хранить?)

Comment: Ну и решения с парсингом выглядит очень сомнительно и костыльно.